# How to pass a string parameter through a method to change the object name?

Tags: c#

I am doing some automation testing using C# and would like to know if its possible to pass in a string value to change an object name?  So the question is regarding the line repo.MainWindow.A201Info.......I would like to pass in the orderNumber i.e. A201,A202,A203 etc and change the A201Info e.g. to A202Info, A203Info etc......is this at all possible?

```
public static bool ChangeAndVerifyNewPriority(string orderNumber, string newPriority)
        {
            bool priorityChanged = false;
                if(repo.SomeElement.SelfInfo.Exists(3000)){
                    Utilities.DoubleClick(repo.MainWindow.A201Info);
                    Utilities.TypeText(repo.Orders.PriorityTextBoxInfo, newPriority);
                    Utilities.LeftClick(repo.Orders.ButtonOKInfo);
                    return priorityChanged=true;
                }
                else{
                    return priorityChanged=false;
                }
```

Comment: What is `Utilities.DoubleClick` expecting to be passed to it? And is eg `A202Info` a property of `MainWindow`?

Comment: No - type information (which includes property and field names) is static and part of the `Type` object for that type.

Comment: @MatthewWatson reflection is a thing.

Comment: @Jamiec Yes, but you can't change a property's name at runtime.

Comment: Of course not, but if all those properties exist on `MainWindow` you could fetch the right one using its name

Comment: @Jamiec Its just a function of automating a double click on some functionality of the software

Comment: @MrRabbit right, and sorry I updated my question to include "And is eg A202Info a property of MainWindow?"

Comment: @MrRabbit So can you confirm if you have a bunch of properties already existing in `MainWindow` called `A201Info`, `A202Info` and so on?

Comment: The problem is I am trying to use this method as a form of a helper class and just pass through some varying parameters

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes they all exist as a bunch of properties but trying to minimize repetition of code i.e. as stated before by placing this in a helper class

Comment: Ah OK so jamiec is correct that you can reflection. I'll let him answer it tho`.

Comment: I can, if you tell me what the type of parameter `Utilities.DoubleClick` takes, also what are the types returned by `A201Info`, `A202Info` etc.

Comment: @Jamiec this is an element property in the software like in selenium for example each feature of the code has elements right, we call it a repository.  Utilities is actually a class file which contains another helper method like mine that goes through the motion of physically clicking a button.  So the type of parameter you are asking is in fact an object in a sense.  The A201Info, A202Info doesn't return a type as such but rather its a phyiscal action (its an object of a specific property)...does this make sense?

Comment: The property _must_ have a return type! You cant define a property without one

Comment: `object`s don't have a name https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 1):

`repo.MainWindow` is an instance, for which you can call `GetType()`, this in turn can be used to reflect and get the public properties. You can also specifically find one by name too. Once you have the property, you can read its value and pass that to `Utilities.DoubleClick`

// I will update with some code once the question in comments is answered.